# How to read jpos QMUX key field programmatically?

Tags: iso8583, multiplexing, jpos

For some reason, I want to read the key I have set inside the QMUX config file (20_client_mux.xml)  with `<key>37</key>`.I could not find any way from jpos itself, so I am using the below code to get things done. I want to do it without using Reflection and I am happy if there is no need for creating a subclass extending either `QMUX` or `XMLConfigurable`.

```java
    import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

    private static String getUniqueFieldId() {
            final String[][] key = {new String[1]};
            ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(QMUX.class, field -> {
                if (field.getName().equals("key")) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    key[0] = (String[]) field.get(mux);
                }
            });
            return key[0][0];
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After all, I was able to access the keys through a short and single line of code and there is no need to create a new class just for this purpose.

```java
mux.getPersist().getChildTextTrim("key");
```

Comment: Nice hack, how did I miss that !!

Comment: Yes! Nice hack! Way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend QMUX, implement `XMLConfigurable` and call `getChildTextTrim("key")` on the XML Element. Remember of course to call `super.setXmlConfiguration`.

Relevant code is at  [QMUX lines 78-87](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/149800935828a2054c5e74d950d5c6aae7dad29c/jpos/src/main/java/org/jpos/q2/iso/QMUX.java#L78-L87):

```java
        key = toStringArray(DEFAULT_KEY, ", ", null);
        returnRejects = cfg.getBoolean("return-rejects", false);
        for (Element keyElement : e.getChildren("key")) {
            String mtiOverride = QFactory.getAttributeValue(keyElement, "mti");
            if (mtiOverride != null && mtiOverride.length() >= 2) {
                mtiKey.put (mtiOverride.substring(0,2), toStringArray(keyElement.getTextTrim(), ", ", null));
            } else {
                key = toStringArray(e.getChildTextTrim("key"), ", ", DEFAULT_KEY);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend QMUX and add a `public getKey()` method, like:

```java
package mypackage;

import org.jpos.q2.iso.QMUX;

public class MyQMUX extends QMUX {
  public String[] getKey() {
    return key;
  }
}
```

Then in the xml deploy descriptor use your `QMUX` implementation:

```xml
<mux class="mypackage.MyQMUX" ...>
...
</mux>
```